# Broadcast Receiver is not working when application is removed from background?

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to run this code in my mobile app, but it is not running and also giving no error. I have tried printing log also, but it is not showing anything in logcat. This problem only occur in Oreo and run well in all other Android versions, also runs well when application is in background.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   AlarmManager am;
    TimeAlarm timeAlarm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        setOneTimeAlarm();
    }

    public void setOneTimeAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    }

    public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("ondestroy","ondestroy");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("onstart","onstart");

        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter("my.custom.action.tag.fordemo");
        intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        registerReceiver(timeAlarm,intentFilter);
    }
}
```

Code Of broadcast receiver, when I have removed the application from background it stopped working.

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    NotificationManager nm;
    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Channel Name";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    nm = (NotificationManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                        channelId, channelName, importance);
                nm.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            } else {

            }
            CharSequence from = "Nithin";
            CharSequence message = "Crazy About Android...";
            PendingIntent contentIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
            //Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.logo, 
           "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
            NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new 
            NotificationCompat.Builder(context.getApplicationContext());
            // notification.setContentIntent(pintent);
       notification.setTicker(from).setSubText(from).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                notification.setChannelId(channelId);
            }

            Notification notification1 = notification.build();
            notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message,contentIntent);
            nm.notify(1, notification1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you have addredd permissions in your manifest?

Comment: about which permission u r asking

Comment: I'll write them into an answer

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be working when in the background on any version of the OS.  You're registering the receiver in onStart, then unregistering in onStop.  That means the receiver, to the OS, does not exist after onStop is processed.  If you're seeing it work on other versions of the OS, that's actually a bug.

Comment: i removed code from onstop..but still its not working.And i also change the code

Answer (score 0):

Sure, your `broadcast` is killed when your application is closed. If you dont `unregisterReceiver` in `onStop`/`onDestroyed`, you will have a leak issue. To avoid it,
you should implement a `Service` (and call `registerReceiver(timeAlarm,intentFilter);` in your service) which runs in the background even when your application is closed.

P/s: remember to `startForeground` to prevent service from being killed by system in Android 8.0 or above.

Comment: I don't  understand can u explain this by example....or send screenshots.... if used it anywhere

Comment: @jyotisharma you should use `Service` to register your `intentFilter` instead of registering in your Application. Here's the `Service` tutorial you should take a look at: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to add alarm permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

And also To register your broadcast

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcast.ServiceBroadcast"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="RestartServices">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="restart_services"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```